# UIkit Animations and Core Animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

I am a beginner iOS programmer. I would like to know what is the limit of the UIView  animations methods, in other world when to use Core animation ? my problem is, i have seen many application witch animate her views, but i don't know if they use core animation to do this or just the UIKit animations.

Thansk for your answer

Comment: You can read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959559/uiview-animation-vs-core-animation

Comment: I would use UIKit for animation, rather messing around with CAnimaiton library. As, it does lot of the heavy lifting and simpler too for getting around. I would recommend you to go through [Apple Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html) for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the UIView animation are fine for the vast majority of animations.  You usually use core animation only if you're going to be performing more advanced animation paths, manipulating a lot of layers simultaneously, or just need to do something that UIView animations can't achieve.  But in my application I use UIView animations for almost everything (including 3D transforms) and I don't have any problem with it.  You wouldn't want to use UIView animations for a game, but for most non-game applications it should be fine.  Besides, UIView animations use core animation on the back end.